# How to add custom data in blockchain during chaincode deployment?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I know that we can invoke smart contract function during chaincode deployment for initial data. But is there any other way around by which we can do the same thing ? Like calling some external function or external service to do the same thing ?

Answer (score 0):

You only update the ledger by submitted endorsed transactions to the orderer, and you got those endorsed transactions by invoking smart contract transaction functions. So I don't think you really have an alternative to invoking a smart contract transaction function to populate the ledger with some initial state after chaincode deployment, but you could provide a function or service that wraps that transactions submission so your client (or deployment process) doesn't need to deal with Fabric directly.